# How does かもしれない integrate into this sentence

Tags: grammar

For full context see here:
https://www.docdroid.net/oraqSdS/img-20170830-0001-new.pdf

The sentence is from 21-22:
聖人君子か大うそつきか、または自分がエラーをしていることに気が付いていないか、忘れてしまっている一番困ったひと**かもしれない**。

First, I wouldn't have a problem with this sentence if the bold かもしれない was か+も+知れない, but since the kanji　is lacking I guess it is just かもしれない indicating that the speaker feels very unsure about smthg..

I interprete the か after 大うそつきか etc. as the か marking an indirect question. Since there is no question word like なに どう etc I'd expect かどうか but there already was the case that かどうか wasn't used and instead just か has been applied (I asked about this here and I was told that it was perfectly normal that this could happen).

Now, here my translation:
"It could be a perfect person or a big liar, or someone who doesn't notice the mistakes he makes himself, or a person who is troubled by forgetting (forgetfulness?) the most."

What's also confusing me is that 困ったひと**かもしれない** lacks another か between かもしれない and ひと. I'd say that 困った人 also belongs to this long chain of indirect questions. I've never learnt that the last part of such a chain could omit its か. But maybe I got it wrong in the first place, thats why Im asking ^^

Answer (score 3):

> 聖人君子**か**大うそつき**か**、または自分がエラーをしていることに気が付いていない**か**、忘れてしまっている一番困ったひとかもしれない。

These か's mean "or".
かもしれない means "might be".

The basic construction of this sentence is:

> AかBか、またはCか、Dかもしれない。"It might be A, B, C, or D."

A = 聖人君子  a perfect person
B = 大うそつき a big liar
C = 自分がエラーをしていることに気が付いていない
(he) hasn't noticed that he made mistakes
D = (自分がエラーをしていることを)忘れてしまっている一番困ったひと
The most troublesome/hopeless person who has forgotten that he made mistakes

「忘れてしまっている」 is a relative clause modifying 「（一番困った）人」.
The object of 「忘れてしまっている」 is 「自分がエラーをしていること」. "Has forgotten that he made mistakes."

"It could be a perfect person, a big liar, or someone who doesn't notice that he made mistakes, or the most troublesome/hopeless person who has forgotten that he made mistakes."

---

I think it could also be interpreted this way:

> AかBか、またはCかもしれない。"It might be A, B, or C."

A = 聖人君子  a perfect person
B = 大うそつき a big liar
C = 自分がエラーをしていることに気が付いていないか、忘れてしまっている一番困ったひと
The most troublesome/hopeless person who hasn't noticed or has forgotten that he made mistakes.

「自分がエラーをしていることに気が付いていないか、忘れてしまっている」 is a long relative clause modifying 「（一番困った）人」.

"It could be a perfect person, a big liar, or the most troublesome/hopeless person who doesn't notice or has forgotten that he made mistakes."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where to start, so it'll be a cluster of many answers, which will hopefully lead you on the right path.

First of all, as for your translation, there is a certain nuance of the word [忘]{わす}れる I'd like to point out:

> **わす・れる【忘れる】**
>
> 何かに熱中してうっかり気がつかずにいる。
>
> 「美しさに我を―・れる」「時のたつのを―・れる」「寝食を―・れて働く」
>
> **Source: [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BF%98%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-665154#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)**

With this in mind, I believe the correct translation should be as follows:

> They may be a perfect person, or a big liar, they may not see the mistakes they make themself or they may lose themself completely in their own problems.

As for かもしれない being this way, not written かも[知]{し}れない, I believe it's not uncommon practice to omit kanji.

Secondly, the grammar structure used in this phrase is bunch of thrown in suggestions, bound with the か particle, which end with the final guessing structure かもしれない.

Lastly, I don't think final part needs か before かもしれない, since it's already there. To follow up on this, I've always tried to reverse-engineer grammar structures like this one to better understand their meaning. I like to think about this one this way: "...I couldn't know better, X may also be the case".

If there's anything else you'd like to ask, I'll be waiting in the comment section. o/